# how to write confusion matrix from given information?

Tags: python-3.x

Vaccine cost is $10. If a child is vaccinated, there is only chance of 10% getting infected. If a kid get infected, the cost of treatment is about $1000. Write down the cost-benefit matrix(Confusion matrix with cost information) for this problem.

what are the values of TP, FN, FP and TN?

Comment: This would probably be better suited for stats and not SO. But with the current format I don't know if anyone would help you on either site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Unable to get started

Comment: I don't think it has enough information to make a confusion matrix.